# Hazelcast / Eureka / Hazelcast-eureka-one custom instance info

Tags: hazelcast, netflix-eureka

Is anyone using the Hazelcast-eureka-one dependency? How do you override the Eureka instance info like the homepageurl, healthcheckurl, etc? Seems like it ignores all the standard eureka client properties.

EDIT: Or should I just scrap the Eureka-one plugin and follow the Hazelcast spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client sample?

Not sure what one offers over the other? eureka-one doesn't seem to be too active?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the standard Eureka client parameters, then you need to let the default mechanism create the Eureka Client and use it in the [following manner](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-eureka#reusing-existing-eurekaclient-instance).

```
EurekaOneDiscoveryStrategyFactory.setEurekaClient(eurekaClient);
```